# Cambiar estado de orden json

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

Me quiero conectar a la api de woocommerce de wordpress para cambiarle el estado a un pedido.

```
            $orderId = $dataObj->result->order_id;

            $url_API_woo = 'https://misitio/';
            $ck_API_woo = 'user';
            $cs_API_woo = 'pass';

            $woocommerce = new Client(
                $url_API_woo,
                $ck_API_woo,
                $cs_API_woo,
                ['version' => 'wc/v3']
            );
            // ================================

            // Conexión API origen
            // ===================
            $url_API="/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/"$orderId;

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_API);

            echo "➜ Obteniendo datos origen ... \n";
            $items_origin = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            if ( ! $items_origin ) {
                exit('❗Error en API origen');
            }

            $items_origin = json_decode($items_origin, true);

            $data = [
                'status' => 'Pago no procesado'
            ];
            
            $woocommerce->put('orders/'$orderId, $data);
```

Este ejemplo lo tome de otro lado, entiendo que se conecta a la api con las credenciales y convierte la respuesta en json, pero no sabría como hacer para decirle que cambie el estado de la orden.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Te recomiendo [leer la documentación](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-properties). El estado que le estas pasando no es una opción.

Comment: Pues la idea es agregar un estado personalizado.

Comment: Entonces te dejo este otro link [WooCommerce Plugin Developer Handbook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/). PD: el título de la pregunta no refleja lo que comentas.